# Нужно найти объект в БД с именем содержащимся в тексте

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Мне нужно отыскать лист объектов Document в БД, имя которых содержится в тексте.

Пример:

Имя документа "XXX"

Текст "... **XXX** ...".

Пытался использовать несколько вариантов поиска, но ничего не выходит.

```
@Query("select d from Document d where d.name like %:text%")
List<Document> getDocumentsByText(String text);

List<Document> getDocumentsByNameIgnoreCaseContains(String text);

List<Document> getDocumentsByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String text);
```

Ни один вариант не срабатывает.

Проблема в том, что я и с SQL и Hibernate знаком шапочно, и не очень понимаю как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось что я неправильно ищу.
Запрос `select d from Document d where d.name like %:text%` искал текст в названии (а текст намного больше), а не название в тексте.

Решение таково:

```
@Query("select d from Document d where locate(d.name, ?1) > 0")
List<Document> getDocumentsByText(@Param("text") String text);
```

При использовании метода locate() он нашёл нужные мне данные.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select d from Document d where d.name like %:text%") 
List<Document> getDocumentsByText(@Param("text") String text);
```

Comment: Не срабатывает, ничего не находит. :(

Comment: Тогда выкладывайте больше кода, возможно ошибка где-то еще. Указанный мной вариант успешно работает в моем проекте.

Comment: Этот поиск чувствителен к регистру